# pigpio: Bad I2C Bus

Tags: i2c, pigpio

I'm trying to start an I2c communication with my Raspberry Pi using the pigpio library. It works fine for me with SPI, but I really do struggle with I2C.

When I use

```
if (gpioInitialize() < 0) printf("Coudn't initialize gpio");
i2c_handle = i2cOpen(0, 0b1100000, 0);
```

I always get back -74 as handle, which stands for PI_BAD_I2C_BUS.

Can somebody explain that to me? The bus number I give to the function is 0, that should be totaly valid. But I also tried some different numbers and I always get this same error...

Comment: What model Pi are you using? What happens if you try this i2c_handle = i2cOpen(1, 0b1100000, 0);

Comment: I use a Raspberry Pi 3. No matter what bus number I use, there is always the same return.

Comment: did you enable i2c in `raspi-config`?

Comment: Ok, that actually was the problem. Embarrassing. But I don't understand, I didn't enable SPI either, and that worked just fine from the beginning.
Can I somehow mark your comment as solution, despite it's not an answer?

Comment: @crasic, hi, I would like to invite you to post that solution as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error:

```
raspberrypi $ python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pigpio
>>> mypi = pigpio.pi()
>>> myi2c = mypi.i2c_open(1, 0x1E)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 2644, in i2c_open
    self.sl, _PI_CMD_I2CO, i2c_bus, i2c_address, 4, extents))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 979, in _u2i
    raise error(error_text(v))
pigpio.error: 'bad I2C bus'
```

And I eventually figured out that you need to enable I2C on the raspberry pi:

`sudo raspi-config`

And select `5 Interfacing Options` -> `P5 - I2C` -> `Yes` to enable I2C

You can then check if I2C is enabled by looking in `/dev/`

```
raspberrypi $ ls -l /dev/i2c*
crw-rw---- 1 root i2c 89, 1 Apr 14 19:13 /dev/i2c-1
```